# Flexslider - on touch

Tags: views, 7, theming

I am using Flexslider module in drupal 7 .  when i checked my website on mobile.  i am not use slider by touch

Is there is any setting for flexslider.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable touch for that. Follow this path for flexslider setting `$base_url/admin/config/media/flexslider/list/default/edit`.

You will see screen such as [image]
You need to check Touch in Navigation and Control Settings & save.

Don't forget to clear cache :)

Comment: i already enable, when i am checking on mobile. it is not touch behaviour

Comment: @Hitu - It works for me with these settings :)

Comment: i checked twice and  thrice . not working :(